# Python Soundcloud SDK Upload track

Tags: python, soundcloud

I am working on an application that calls the soundcloud api, in this case to upload a track using the python soundcloud SDK (https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#uploading-files)

I have verified that the token is valid to discard that case, and this is the code that does the request:

```
import soundcloud
import sys, json

def uploadTrack(token, title, file):
  # create a client object with access token
  client = soundcloud.Client(access_token=token)

  # upload audio file
  track = client.post('/tracks', track={
    'title': title,
    'downloadable': 'true',
    'asset_data': open(file, 'rb')
  })
```

On the result callback, i got the following error

```
Error: requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks
```

However, when i check user's soundcloud account , the track appears there (sucessfully uploaded).

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The response has a header field `Status: 201 Created` and it has the correct `Location` header with the new track URL, but the response itself has a status code of 401. Seems like a configuration error on SoundCloud's end

Comment: There's [a bug report](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python/issues/68) in the soundcloud-python issue tracker.

Comment: @Jayson, it might be useful to post that in the bug report, and also just mention that you're being affected. I can do it for you if you want. agarzon, you might also want to mention there that you're being affected by this.

Comment: @Cyphase I'm not actually using the python sdk myself (I have my own wrapper around the HTTP API for my iOS app) but I'll add my info to that bug report